# How do I add Text before my answer in the text box using setAttribute but only after the resullt has been printed

Tags: javascript

I want it to read the-number-that-has-been-computed)  where the-number-that-has-been-computed is the result of the addition of the first two text boxes( I am also using window.onload that is why my script is in the head of the file.

```js
function setUpEvents() {
  function add_number() {
    var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("tb1").value);
    var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("tb2").value);
    var result = first_number + second_number;
    document.getElementById("tb3").value = result;
  };
}
window.onload = function() {
  setUpEvents();
};
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Add two number using text box as input using javascript</h1>
</div>
Enter First Number : <br>
<input type="text" id="tb1" name="TextBox1">
<br> Enter Second Number : <br>
<input type="text" id="tb2" name="TextBox2">
<br> Result : <br>
<input type="text" id="tb3" name="TextBox3">
<br>
<input type="button" name="b1" value="GO" onclick="add_number()">
```

Comment: `onclick="add_number()"` won't work because it's not accessible in that scope.

Comment: Your scope is broken. Why wrap the function in a function. Just have it in the head and call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the setUpEvents to not have the function out of scope for the inline event handler

Also remove the inline event handler

Use eventListeners instead. I changed the name to id for the button

```js
function add_number() {
  var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("tb1").value);
  var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("tb2").value);
  var result = first_number + second_number;
  document.getElementById("tb3").value = "The-number-that-has-been-computed is "+ result;
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", add_number);
});
```

```css
input { width: 300px }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Add two number using text box as input using javascript</h1>
</div>
Enter First Number : <br>
<input type="text" id="tb1" name="TextBox1">
<br> Enter Second Number : <br>
<input type="text" id="tb2" name="TextBox2">
<br> Result : <br>
<input type="text" id="tb3" name="TextBox3">
<br>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="GO" />
```

Comment: @MRPLUNGJAN I have done your snippet of code but how would I add text of The-number-that-has-been-computed so it would display in font of the answer when submitted in the 3rd text box

Comment: I want a string      "The-number-that-has-been-computed"  to print in front of my result how would i do this

Comment: Perfect thank you very much! ps i will upvote this once i have 15 reputation lol.

Comment: How would I achieve this same outcome using "setAttribute" just curious

Comment: You mean document.getElementById("b1").setAttribute("value","bla bla "+result)

Comment: Yes that what exactly i mean:) how would that affect my code up above

Comment: Just replace `document.getElementById("tb3").value = "The-number-that-has-been-computed is "+ result;` with `document.getElementById("tb3").setAttribute("value", "The-number-that-has-been-computed is "+ result);`